# Subtract vector from list

Tags: r, list, vector, subtraction

How to perform such operation:

```
a <- list(b=1, c=c(2,3))
d <- c(1,1,2)
e <- list(b=0, c=c(1,1))
```

I am trying to subtract: a - d = e. But in theory we cannot subtract vector from list and get list with the same structure. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: It's not clear what "a - d = e" should produce. What is your goal?

Comment: You want to subtract a vector from a list of vectors, where the total number of elements is the same in both cases?

Comment: Yes, i need result in form of a list e.

Comment: Your problem made more sense before the edit. Where are the `e` and `f` list names in the final answer supposed to come from?

Comment: Good point, sorry for that change. I will change it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [relist](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/relist.html) and `unlist`:

```
> relist(unlist(a) - d, a)

$b
[1] 0

$c
[1] 1 1
```